# How to avoid spinning up multiple contexts in entity framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework

In Entity framework, trying to run the following code:

```
        using (MyEntities ctx = new myEntities())
        {
            Entity.Customers.Build buildId = new ctx.Build();
            buildId.CustomerService = customerService;
            buildId.datCreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            buildId.strBuildSchema = schema;
            buildId.Status = "Success";
            ctx.AddToBuilds(buildId);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Results in the error "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker".

As far as I can tell, the problem is that the Build object I'm creating comes from a new instance of the Entity Framework context which is distinct from the context that does the AddToBuilds() statement.

However I can't work out how to get past this problem. I can't seem to create a new Build direct from an instantiation of the Entity context object i.e. ctx in the code above? Is there a way to do this, or am I missing another obvious workaround?

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're associating an entity which is attached to one context, not shown in the code above (`customerService`?) with another entity, `buildId`, which is attached to `ctx`. Don't do that. Use one context at a time.

Answer (score 0):

"customerService" (or perhaps 'schema') belongs to another EntityTracker. The simplest way to get rid of this is to add the following line of code in the code *which loaded customerService* (note, making an assumption about the class name of customerService here):

```
ctx.CustomerService.MergeOptions = MergeOptions.NoTracking;
```

This line of code tells the context "I'm not going to be making any changes to CustomerService objects, so don't bother tracking them".